# Overlay a webview over an Image view

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I don't have the actual code since I haven't started working on it. I want a background image to appear on my app all the time and I want to overlay a `webview` over it( the web view would have no background colors, just few buttons that say for instance Login & Signup etc.) What are my options to get this done? 
If I am being vague, let me know.

Comment: `webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);` will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your image as its backgroud

```
mWebview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.amanda);
mWebview.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); // change this as you need
```

[image]
[image]